# Laravel 5 Eloquent model dynamically generated at runtime

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I am looking to make some sort of "GenericModel" class extending Eloquent's `Model` class, that can load database configuration (like connection, table name, primary key column) as well as relationships at runtime based on a configuration JSON file.

My reasons for wanting this are as follows: I'm going to have a lot of database tables and thus a lot of models, but most don't really have any complicated logic behind them. I've developed a generic CRUD API and front-end interface to interact with them. Each model has a "blueprint" JSON file associated with it that describes things like its attributes and relationships. This lets me automatically generate, say, a view to create a new model and it knows what attributes I need to fill in, what input elements to use, what to label them, which are mandatory, how to validate, whether to check for uniqueness, etc. without ever needing code specific to that model. Here's an example, `project.json`:

```
{
    "db_table": "projects",
    "primary_key": "projectid",
    "display_attr": "title", // Attribute to display when picking row from list, etc
    "attributes": {
        "projectid": { // Attribute name matches column name
            "display": "ID", // Display this to user instead of db column name
            "data_type": "integer" // Can be integer, string, numeric, bool...
        },
        "title": {
            "data_type": "string",
            "unique": true // Check for uniqueness when validating field
        },
        "customer": {
            "data_type": "integer", // Data type of local key, matches customer PK
            "relationship": { // Relationship to a different model
                "type": "manytoone",
                "foreign_model": "customer"
            },
            "user": "autocomplete" // User input element/widget to use, queries customer model for matches as user types
        },
        "description": {
            "data_type": "string",
            "user": "textarea" // Big string, use <textarea> for user input
            "required": false // Can be NULL/empty, default true
        }
    },
    "views": {
        "table": [ // Show only these attributes when viewing table
            "customer",
            "title"
        ],
        "edit_form": [ // Show these when editing
            "customer",
            "title",
            "description"
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

This works extremely well on the front end, I don't need any more information than this to describe how my models behave. Problem is I feel like I just end up writing this all over again in most of my `Model` classes and it seems much more natural to have them just pull information from the blueprint file as well. This would result in the information being in one place rather than two, and would avoid extra effort and possible mistakes when I change a database table and only need to update one file to reflect it.

I'd really just like to be able to do something like `GenericModel::blueprint('project.json')->find($id)` and get a functioning "product" instance. Is this possible, or even advisable? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `GenericModel` could extend `Eloquent`, and in that way you could read the configuration in the constructor & set the appropriate values. You could also create a static `blueprint()` method which would return a properly instantiated `GenericModel` instance. BUT, one concern - how do you tell these things apart? ie. How do you know this instance is for table X instead of table Y? This may not be a big concern, depending on your database scheme.

Comment: Another question/concern... if your tables are so similar that you can do this, why bother with Eloquent at all? You're clearly not using relationships. Maybe you could just build your own simple model class...

Comment: @Kryten - I actually did just start making a `GenericRepository` class that simply returned arrays for table rows (good enough when my controller just generates JSON responses), but felt like I was reinventing the wheel. I'm not using Eloquent to its fullest potential with this for sure, but it still offers a lot of conveniences I would like to use. Your comment about not knowing what table an instance is from is valid, but I'm not sure it would present a problem for me. I definitely am using relationships, though.

Comment: I'm starting to think that just writing an Artisan command to auto-generate model class files from blueprints is the right way to go here. Should be pretty straightforward to implement and solves the don't-repeat-yourself problem while making everything fit with the standard Eloquent implementation. Think I could even store the hash of the blueprint in the header of the generated file and automatically run the command before loading the class if it is found to be out of date during a request, meaning I don't even have to run the command myself.

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at [**Migrations**](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#writing-migrations) (was Schema Builder)? It allows you to programatically build models (from JSON if necessary).

Then you could leverage Eloquent on your queries...